# Proposal: rename tag: exist to exist-db

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

I would propose renaming the [exist](/questions/tagged/exist) (EDIT: and [existdb](/questions/tagged/existdb) - thanks Kevin!) tags into [exist-db](/questions/tagged/exist-db). Maybe this prevents erroneous tagging of question about "how do i check if a file **exists**?" with [exist](/questions/tagged/exist). The [exist-db logo](http://www.exist-db.org/logo.jpg) logo may show "exist" prominently, but AFAIK all relevant resources (Domain, download packages, mailinglists and so on) use the name "exist-db".

EDIT: renaming would be reasonable since, e.g., QTP/VBScript has a function "exist", so the [exist](/questions/tagged/exist) tag [seems to be relevant here, too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8007862/342546), despite exist-db and QTP/VBScript are completely different matters.

Comment: The [tag:existdb] tag should also be merged into the proposed [tag:exist-db].

Comment: @KevinCathcart: thanks for your comment, you're right - i've emendet my proposal accordingly.

Comment: [tag:exist] is no more and the tag has been renamed to [tag:exist-db].